# C# Regular Expression: {4} and more then 4 values possible

Tags: c#, regex

I'm in need of a regular expression that checks if the input is exactly 4 numbers.
I'm using "\d{4}" (also tried "\d\d\d\d").
But if you enter 5 numbers, it also says the input is valid.

```
  [TestMethod]
    public void RegexTest()
    {
        Regex expr = new Regex("\\d{4}");
        String a = "4444", b = "4l44", c = "55555", d = "5 55";
        Match mc = expr.Match(a);
        Assert.IsTrue(mc.Success);

        mc = expr.Match(b);
        Assert.IsFalse(mc.Success);
        ***mc = expr.Match(c);
        Assert.IsFalse(mc.Success)***;
        mc = expr.Match(d);
        Assert.IsFalse(mc.Success);
    }
```

(it's the c that  is 'true' but should be false, the others work)

Thanks in advance,
~Sir Troll

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it must be *exactly* 4, then you need to use $ and ^ to mark end and start of the input:

```
Regex expr = new Regex(@"^\d{4}$");
```

Note I'm also using verbatim string literals here, so save on sanity - then you don't need to C#-escape all your regex-escape-characters. Only `"` needs escaping in the C# (to `""`).

Answer (score 2):

"55555" contains "5555", which is valid... So the string contains a match, even though the match isn't the complete string. See Marc's answer for the solution

Answer (score 1):

a string with 5 digits also *contains* 4 digits, so you have to make sure that you also add start and end of string contraints.

This should work as your Regex:

```
Regex expr = new Regex(@"^\d{4}$");
```